# checkbox to hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

This is part of a script that hides/shows a particular category of markers on a Google map when the corresponding checkbox is checked.

```
  function boxclick(box,category) {
    if (box.checked) {
      show(category);
    } else {
      hide(category);
    }
```

What I am trying to do is also hide any div's on the page which have the same id as this category.

Is implementing something into the script like this possible? Rather than creating a separate onclick event. I would like to try and do this all from the same code.

```
  function boxclick(box,category) {
    if (box.checked) {
      show(category);
      $("#"+category).show();
    } else {
      hide(category);
      $("#"+category).hide();
    }
```

EDIT: Apologies meant div ID not name

Comment: instead of passing category can you pass id of that div? Then you can easily hide or show that div.

Comment: You say your divs have names? That should not happen. MDN has [a list of attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes), divs may have. `name` is not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah you can simply do it like this

```
  function boxclick(box,category) {
        if (box.checked) {
          show(category);
          $("div#"+category).show();
        } else {
          hide(category);
           $("div#"+category).hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the divs have a name attribute, e.g:

```
<div name="toggleMe">I'll disappear</div>
<div name="dontToggleMe">I won't disappear</div>
<div name="toggleMe">I'll also disappear</div>
```

Then yes, that's possible.

Try a function like this:

```
function boxclick(box,jquerySelector) {
  if (box.checked) {
    $(jquerySelector).show();
  } else {
    $(jquerySelector).hide();
  }
};
```

into which you can pass a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that matches all divs with the required name attribute, e.g

```
boxclick(this,"div[name='toggleMe'"]);
```

Here's a jsFiddle of a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/787Hy/